# ¿Como puedo agregar un div con un img debajo de divs previos con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Que tal mi problema es el siguiente, estoy tratando de agregar un arreglo que previamente construyo

```
/*CAROUSEL*/
        $('.imgSlide_1').attr('src', data.allData.demoGif);
        $('.imgSlide_2').attr('src', data.allData.principalImage);

        var imgContent = [];
        $.each(data.imagenes, function (key, imagenSrc) {
           imgContent += ' <div class="item">';
           imgContent += ' <img class="imgSlide_0_'+key+' border shadow-sm rounded" src="'+imagenSrc+'" alt="0_'+key+' slide">';
           imgContent += ' </div>';

        });
        //$('.item').after(imgContent);

        $('#imgSrc').append(imgContent);

        console.log(" arreglo de img: " + imgContent);
```

del lado del HTML tengo los tags así

```
<div class="item">
    <img class="imgSlide_1 border shadow-sm rounded" src="" alt="1 slide">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img class="imgSlide_2 border shadow-sm rounded" src="" alt="2 slide">
</div>
<div class="item" id="imgSrc">
</div>
```

El css

```
#demos .owl-carousel .item {
position: relative;
padding: 1rem;
}
#demos .owl-carousel .item > img {
position: relative;
height: 17rem;
}
```

y lo que obtengo en el carousel son las imágenes pero se van hacia abajo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que necesito es que sigan la misma estructura que los divs previos.

El resultado que estoy buscando es que se creen los **divs dinámicamente**, algo así

```
<div class="item">
    <img class="imgSlide_1 border shadow-sm rounded" src="" alt="1 slide">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img class="imgSlide_2 border shadow-sm rounded" src="" alt="2 slide">
</div>
<div class="item" id="imgSrc">
    <img class="imgSlide_3 border shadow-sm rounded" src="" alt="3 slide">
</div> 
<div class="item" id="imgSrc">
    <img class="imgSlide_4 border shadow-sm rounded" src="" alt="4 slide">
</div>  
<div class="item" id="imgSrc">
    <img class="imgSlide_5 border shadow-sm rounded" src="" alt="5 slide">
</div>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Al intentar agregar un arreglo de imágenes con jquery al carousel pierde el estilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/305727/al-intentar-agregar-un-arreglo-de-im%c3%a1genes-con-jquery-al-carousel-pierde-el-esti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria bueno que agregues tu CSS para ver que tienes en tu clase `.item`, sin embargo el que te esta dando el salto es el div.
Intenta esto:

```
$.each(data.imagenes, function (key, imagenSrc) {
      $('#imgSrc').append(' <img class="imgSlide_0_'+key+' border shadow-sm rounded" src="'+imagenSrc+'" alt="0_'+key+' slide">');
    });
```

Con esto te los agregara a tu #imgSrc, el cual te sugiero que sea un `<div id='imgSrc'>`.

Comment: Que tal Bernardo, actualizo mi pregunta con el fragmento de css